Directory of Vegan Communities in Ecuador (South America)
Where can I find a directory of vegan communities in Ecuador?
I'm currently eating a mostly raw vegan diet, and I'm trying to transition to more of a fruitarian diet. But living in Northern Europe, the fruit options here are very limited. I've learned about a few vegan communities in Ecuador that I'd like to visit, but information about them is sparse.
I'm going on a trip to South America soon to visit Ecuador. If I search travel.stackexchange.com for "vegan ecuador", there's 0 results. I've tried googling for "vegan ecuador," but most of the results are just about restaurants. I don't care much for capitalism, eating at a restaurant, or "eco-tourism" (veganism isn't a diet!). I am looking to learn about vegan projects in Ecuador, possibly joining a vegan intentional community there.
But first, to plan my trip, I'd like to get a list of all the vegan intentional communities in Ecuador.
Are there any lists of actual vegan communities in Ecuador?

I found a website with a map of vegan intentional communities in Ecuador:

https://www.eco-libre.org/vegan-communities-ecuador/









map source



The map shows 11 communities: 7 strictly-vegan plus 4 vegetarian (or mostly-vegetarian) communities. Some of them are clustered together, so it's hard to see without zooming-in, but the link above has an interactive map and lists all the communities with links to their websites for more info.
Most of them are located in the Amazon and are focused on reforestation or conservation of some kind. Many are raw vegan or high-raw or fruit-based (much of the volunteer work appears to be dedicated to growing fruit tree forests).

Five seconds of googling "vegan Ecuador society" gave me The Complete List of Vegan Intentional Communities  which has a section for Central and South America which lists 4 vegan communities in Ecuador.
Las Aguas Risas, Laughing Waters Vegan Community
Peaceful Village Raw Vegan Healing Community
Fruit Haven Ecovillage
Terra Frutis

The obvious link: https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=vegan+Ecuador+society

@Jakuje I seriously thought of that, but the OP doesn't have an established pattern of asking questions with no research - unlike other, well known profiles.  So I'm cutting them some slack.
